# How do I setup access codes for shared printers?

Tags: macos, printing

We've got a RICOH Aficio MP C4501 in our office that supports holding print jobs pending having a code input at the keypad (so sensitive documents don't print until you're able to be present to pick them up).  I'm not finding a way to set that code in the Apple print dialog, not even the setup dialog.  How do I go about using this codes feature on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a call back from RICOH.  It's under the "Job Log" drop-down menu in the print dialog.  User ID, password, codes, and controls (hold vs. locked), etc can all be set there!